# Classes, Mixins ou os Dois?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Atualmente em meus projetos comecei a usar `Classes` em JS, principalmente em casos relacionados a determinado elemento especifico, por exemplo, o Usuário, todas as requisições `HTTP` ou métodos relacionados a ele eu costumo isolar em duas classes para facilitar o reaproveitamento. No fim acabo criando um `Usuario.js` e `UsuarioService.js`. O primeiro apenas com atributos, getters e setters. E o segundo com os demais métodos.

Porém já vi muitos utilizando `Mixins` com a mesma finalidade. Vocês sabem qual das formas seria mais condizente com as boas práticas de desenvolvimento do Vue? Usar preferencialmente Mixin, Classe ou até mesmo os dois juntos?

**Obs:** Antes eu usava mixins também, porém comecei a usar mais classes, pois percebi que as pessoas que não conheciam o **VueJS** tinham mais facilidade em dar manutenção em códigos com classes do que com mixins, além de entenderem bem mais rápido o que estava se passando no código.

Comment: Pergunta muito interessante mas as respostas podem ser baseadas em opinião pessoal. O grande problema dos mixins a meu ver é que introduzem código de N sitios diferentes e torna muito dificil perceber como o componente funciona. Uma classe que herda de outra classe é mais fácil de seguir o conjunto de funcionalidades que é acrescentado.

Comment: Muito bem apontado @Sergio! Realmente, fica bem mais fácil de seguir as funcionalidades, atualmente eu uso mixin quando preciso utilizar do **created**, **mounted** ou outro recurso do VueJS.

Obrigado por apontar que a pergunta pode remeter a opinião pessoal, vou tentar editar para buscar respostas mais objetivas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vejo muito a vantagem de se usar uma classe só com getters e setters, mas vejo vantagem em usar os serviços, uma abordagem que ajudou a clarear mais as ideias com relação a isso foram esses dois artigos muito bons. Me ajudaram a ver como isolar as camadas e ter um componente mais clean possível.

https://blog.codecasts.com.br/vue-js-e-servicos-4d4439320a2?gi=f32a0129cd48
https://vuejs-brasil.com.br/injetando-servicos-em-componentes-de-forma-transparente/

Comment: Muito interessante os artigos, me ajudou bastante, muito obrigado pelas informações. Realmente essas classes para getters e setters só me ajudam em casos bem específicos, mas não é nada que o computed ou methods não possam substituir, utilizo elas porque na empresa que trabalho só tem eu no Front, e hora ou outra a galera do back vem dar manutenção em algo, então dessa forma facilita a vida deles, enfim é um caso bem particular e "sugerido" de cima kk.